# How to create a JPA implementation with Spring that is not added to the Spring context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-cache

I'd like to add a cache using Spring and annotations to a repository that uses Spring Data but I'd prefer not to add the cache annotations to the same interface that extends the JpaRepository interface to separate concerns.

I'd like to create a wrapper around the Spring JPA repository defined as follows:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>{
    MyEntity findOneByMyAttribute(String myAttribute);  
}

public interface MyRepositorySpring extends MyRepository {}
```

Spring by default creates an implementation and adds it to the beans context even without an `@Repository` annotation present.

My problem is that I would like to have full control of the beans in the context. I'd like to create a wrapper like this:

```
public class MyCachedRepository extends MyRepository {
    private final MyRepository wrappedRepository;

    @Cacheable
    MyEntity findOneByMyAttribute(String myAttribute){
        wrappedRepository.get(myAttribute);
    }
}
```

where `wrappedRepository` is the implementation created by Spring Data and then create the configuration as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConf {

    @Bean
    public MyRepository myRepository() {
        return new MyCachedRepository(myJpaRepository());
    }

    private MyRepository myJpaRepository() {
        //here I would have the code that generates the implementation 
    }
}
```

Like this I could always have my code injecting a `myRepository` bean and let the configuration decide whether the bean in the context is the wrapped repository or the jpa one as there would be only one at all times.

Is there any way to do this?